# Mongo - Average of the second document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to calculate the average amount order of the 2nd order of my customers.

I succeed to do the average amount of the 1st order using this :

```
db.users.aggregate([
{$match: {
    $and: [
        {$nor : [ { "emails.0.address" : "X@X.com" }, { "X.0.X" : "X@X.com" },{ "emails.0.address" : "X@X.com" },{ "emails.0.address" : "X@X.fr" } ]},
        {orders: {$exists: true}}
    ]
}},
{$unwind: "$orders"},
{$group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    firstOrder: {$first: "$orders"}
}},
{$group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    total: {$sum: "$firstOrder.total"}
}},
{$group: {
    _id: '',
    average: {$avg: "$total"}
}}
```

])

But it seems to be a bit different to calculate the average amount of the 2nd order.

I tried to work with `$Slice` but it does not work with `aggregate` and `$Skip` skip only the first order of the list, but not the first order of each user.

Do you have any idea about this ?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Richard

Answer (score 0):

As you have basically worked out, there is not a simple way to get at the `nth` position of an array. But you were on the right track, just with a bit more processing and an additional tweak. Since you don't want to be processing orders where there is no second order:

```js
db.users.aggregate([

    // Match to make sure there is a second element, $and is actually implicit
    { "$match": {
        "$nor" : [ 
            { "emails.0.address" : "X@X.com" }, 
            { "X.0.X" : "X@X.com" },
            { "emails.0.address" : "X@X.com" },
            { "emails.0.address" : "X@X.fr" } 
        ],
        "orders.1": { "$exists": true }
    }},

    // Then unwind to de-normalize
    { "$unwind": "$orders"},

    // Keep the first order, and all the rest
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "firstOrder": { "$first": "$orders" }
        "orders": { "$push": "$orders" }
    }},

    // Yep, unwind again
    { "$unwind": "$orders"},

    // Test to see the element that was already seen
    { "$project": {
        "orders": 1,
        "matched": { "$eq": [ "$orders", "$firstOrder" ] }
    }},

    // Filter out the matched element
    { "$match": { "matched": false } },

    // Now the $first element is actually the "second"
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "secondOrder": { "$first": "$orders" }
    }},

    // Summing is redundant, just average over all of it
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "average": { "$avg": "$secondOrder.total" }
    }}
])
```

So that cleans things up a bit and gets you the average of the second element by effectively removing the "first" element of the array from the end operations.

If you missed the meaning earlier the line:

```js
        "orders.1": { "$exists": true }
```

Is basically a little "dot notation" trick to make sure that the second element of the array actually exists. There are ways to consider the "first" element of the array when there is actually no second element in this, but that possibly is really another question, if you cannot find the answer to that on here already. And I know I have given ways to deal with varying array lengths before.

Comment: As **orders** is an array, if the second element is equal to the first one in some documents, then some of second order will be lost by **above matched**, which will cause incorrect result.

Comment: @Wizard I would hope that intellegent people would use a unique identifier in here. And since there really is no other way to "slice" an array in the aggregation framework I don't understand the point of your critique. Do you have something intelligent to offer? Or are you just nagging because you didn't think of it first?

Comment: I just talk about the possibility. I think any question and answer is open for discussion on stakoverflow. And people may mistake during asking or answering, all's possible. I'm surprised my comment make you unhappy.

Comment: @Wizard So what do you suggest ? To write `matched": { "$eq": [ "orders.0", "$firstOrder" ] }` ? This actually does not work :/